# Constant eigenvalues under time evolution

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

Consider a separable Hilbert space $H$ (for instance $L^2([0,1])$). Let $A:\mathbb{R}\to \mathcal{O}$ be a $C^1$ function, where $\mathcal{O}$ is the set of linear compact self-adjoint operators $H\to H$.

Is there some general condition on the time derivative $\dot A$ which allows to state that there exists an eigenvalue of $A(0)$ which is an eigenvalue of $A(t)$ for all $t$ (or at least in an open neighbourhood of $t=0$)? Are there general conditions on $\dot A$ which allows to state that none of the eigenvalues of $A(0)$ can be constant?

Apart from trivial cases, such as $\dot A$ is not $t$ dependent and then $A(t) = t A(0)$ or some cases in which an explicit solution can be given, I don't see how to find a general approach to the problem. There is some literature, especially referring to operators which have a role in Quantum Mechanics, about eigenvectors which are preserved, but I couldn't find anything about eigenvalues.

Do you have any reference in mind, for tackling this kind of problems?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax_pair